# How to check match words from the fetch API data in React (functional component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const STARTING_TIME = 10;

  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [timeRemaining, setTimeRemaining] = useState(STARTING_TIME);
  const [isTimeRunning, setIsTimeRunning] = useState(false);
  const [wordCount, setWordCount] = useState(0);
  const textBoxRef = useRef(null);
  const [currWordIndex, setCurrWordIndex] = useState(0);

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setText(value);
  }

  function calculateWordCount(text) {
    const wordsArr = text.trim().split(" ");
    return wordsArr.filter((word) => word !== "").length;
  }

  const [word, setWord] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://excuser.herokuapp.com/v1/excuse");
    const data = await response.json();
    setWord(data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  function startGame() {
    setIsTimeRunning(true);
    setTimeRemaining(STARTING_TIME);
    setText("");
    setCurrWordIndex(0);
    textBoxRef.current.disabled = false;
    textBoxRef.current.focus();
  }

  function endGame() {
    setIsTimeRunning(false);
    setWordCount(calculateWordCount(text));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isTimeRunning && timeRemaining > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setTimeRemaining((time) => time - 1);
      }, 1000);
    } else if (timeRemaining === 0) {
      endGame();
    }
  }, [timeRemaining, isTimeRunning]);

  function handleKeyDown({ keyCode }) {
    if (keyCode === 32) {
      checkMatch();
      setCurrWordIndex(currWordIndex + 1);
    }
  }

  function checkMatch() {
    const wordToCompare = word[currWordIndex];
    const doesItMatch = wordToCompare === text;
    console.log({ doesItMatch });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>How fast do you type?</h1>
      <h1>Type the sentence below</h1>
      <h3>
        {word.map((item) => (
          <h3 key={item.id}>{item.excuse}</h3>
        ))}
      </h3>
      <textarea
        ref={textBoxRef}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={text}
        disabled={!isTimeRunning}
      />
      <h4>Time remaining: {timeRemaining}</h4>
      <button onClick={startGame} disabled={isTimeRunning}>
        Start
      </button>
      <h1>Word count: {wordCount}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have not been able to match the words from the fetch data API with the inputted words in React JS. Does anyone know how to help me solve it using the functional component? Because most answers that I found are using the class component. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Maybe `setWord(data.excuse)`?

Comment: Simply add console.logs to check what are the values of the states that you are trying to compute and you'll be able to reach the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have checked the values that you are comparing in `checkMatch`, as your state `word` is currently an array of object:

```
word: [
 {
  id: 306
  excuse: "Due to heavy rain, the roads around my area were closed."
  category: "college"
 }
]
```

and you are trying to compare it like its an array of words of the given string.

Also, your state `text` is a string consisting of all the text that the user have written till now and not the recent word that user has written.

Below function should work with your current implementation:

```
  function checkMatch() {
    const words = word[0].excuse.split(' ');
    const wordsWritten = text.split(' ');
    const wordToCompare = words[currWordIndex];
    const doesItMatch = wordToCompare === wordsWritten[currWordIndex];

    console.log({ doesItMatch });
  }
```

Although, its not very efficient solution (for larger text) as on every word check you will be splitting the entire text in words to compare.